# Excel formula for days & time

Tags: excel

I am trying to find a formula if (1 11:13) was in one cell, say F2. I could have a formula which showed me cell F2 converted to days. Then another cell showing it converted to hours and another converted to minutes.  Please let me know, if possible.

Comment: Is that `1 11:13` a custom format?  I don't see it in the date format options.  If so, what do the different parts represent, and is the format always going to be consistent?

Answer (score 0):

Let A1=11:13, then B1

```
=IF(TEXT(A1;"hh:mm")="11:13";HOUR(A1);"")
```

and C1 can be

```
=IF(TEXT(A1;"hh:mm")="11:13";MINUTE(A1);"")
```